# Why this VM Script does not add int attribute to xml element?

Tags: xml, velocity

I have this part of VM Script code:

```
$documentBuilder.putMetadata("test_1",$test_1)
$documentBuilder.putMetadata("test_2",$test_2)
(...)
$out.addAttribute("test_2",$test_2)
$out.addAttribute("test_1",$test_1)
```

I expected to return in XML something like:
`<Card test_1="abc" test_2="1">`
Although it returns:
`<Card test_1="abc">`
What do you think is going wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: What does `$test_2` or `$test_2.class.name` output?

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson $test_2 is not outputted anywhere in the XML that's the problem

Comment: Do you mean that you are in a situation where you can't add debugging code to your VTL?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution to my problem. XML attributes are always strings and I was trying to add an integer attribute (`$test_2` had an integer value). So I believe that this is the reason `test_2` attribute didn't appear to the output XML's **Card** element